# Unable to use android library in app1 when creating xamarin project in vs2019

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, using

You have created a project in Xamarin form.
There are 2 projects in the solution.
One is App1 and the other is App1.android.

Declaring using android in the App1 project throws an error.
Can't the original app1 project use the Android library?

Or is there another way? I am new to Xamarin.

Answer (score 1):

App1 is the common project i.e., its common for Android, iOS and UWP. So if u want add any android libraries, we can add it in the app1.android Project.

If you want to achieve any UI specific to android, you can use custom renderers.